# How to prevent more than one LightFace to appear?

Tags: javascript, mootools

Hi guys I am new to programming, especially MooTools. How do I prevent more than one LightFace from opening up?

The plugin is available here: http://davidwalsh.name/facebook-lightbox

Comment: How are you throwing the modals? Are you calling `new LightFace()` each time? If you are, then you are probably using it wrong. Instantiate LightFace once, and then use `.load()` to change the content.

Answer (score 0):

destroy it after completion of work with model.
example

```
keys: { 
          esc: function() { 
                     var r=confirm("Are you sure, you want to do this?");
                            if (r==true){
                                this.close(); 
                                this.destroy();//this you need to do
                                $('overlay').setStyle('display', 'none');
                            }else{}   
                        }
```